# not in the usual way

Tags: negation

a. He opened the envelop not in the usual way.

b. He wrote the letter not in the cursive handwriting he habitually used.

Are these sentences grammatically correct?

I think normally one would expect a 'but' clause after the sentence (He opened the envelop not in the usual way, **but from the side.**), and I was wondering if they could be considered grammatical as they are.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the difference between "grammatical" (which your examples most certainly ***are***), and "idiomatic" (which they most certainly are ***not***).

Answer (score 3):

You are right, to be idiomatic, it needs a 'but'.

Either:

- He opened the envelope, but not in the usual way.

Or, if you wanted to explain the exception:

- He opened the envelope, not in the usual way, but with added enthusiasm.

---

You could also say:

- He opened the envelope in an *unusual* way.

But this means that there was sometimes *strange* about the way he opened it. 'Unusual' is the opposite of what most people would consider usual, not what is usual, or normal for a particular person.